# Guards and where haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a very basic Haskell function. 
It should prepend a tuple to list if not present returning it.
Added tuple needs to be edited before prepending.

I expect a function whose type is this:

```
Num t => (a, t) -> [(a, t)] -> [(a, t)]
```

Function is this:

```
update x lst
| hasElement x lst == True = addElement x lst
| otherwise = lst
where hasElement element list = not (null (filter ((==element).fst) list))
      addElement a b = (fst a, (snd a) +1) : b
```

but I got an error when I try to load the module:

```
• Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a ~ (a, t)
  Expected type: [(a, t)]
    Actual type: [((a, t), t)]
• In the second argument of ‘addElement’, namely ‘lst’
  In the expression: addElement x lst
  In an equation for ‘update’:
      update x lst
        | hasElement x lst == True = addElement x lst
        | otherwise = lst
        where
            hasElement element list
              = not (null (filter ((== element) . fst) list))
            addElement a b = (fst a, (snd a) + 1) : b
• Relevant bindings include
    lst :: [((a, t), t)] (bound at pip.hs:40:10)
    x :: (a, t) (bound at pip.hs:40:8)
    update :: (a, t) -> [((a, t), t)] -> [(a, t)]
      (bound at pip.hs:40:1)
```

The *addElement* return type seems breaks all up since commenting it out makes the module work.

Question is: what's wrong?
Trying function alone seems working as I expect.

Thanks, 
FB

Comment: Always use explicit type signatures, please.

Comment: What does it mean? Got it. I expect a function like this:
Num t => (a, t) -> (a, t) -> [(a, t)]

Comment: Aha. That seems strange though, why would you call an `(a,t)` argument `lst`? I think you mean `(a,t) -> [(a,t)] -> [(a,t)]`. Anyway, please edit the signature into the question, and update the error message accordingly...

Comment: You probably need `(== fst element).fst` instead of `(==element).fst`, since `element` is a pair. Explicitly adding types would help spotting this.

Comment: @leftaroundabout you're right. Edited question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for that particular error is that `element` contains both a key and a value, but by `(==element) . fst` you try to compare only the key.

The best way to actually get only at the key is to pattern match it right in the function argument. Note that you don't really need the `element` variable at all, nor the other arguments to the local functions:

```
update (key,y) lst
  | hasElement  = addElement   -- comparing `==True` is a no-op!
  | otherwise   = lst
 where hasElement = not . null $ filter ((==key).fst) lst
       addElement = (key, y+1) : b
```

I'd question though if this behaviour of `addElement` is really what you want: you're not updating the existing element with a given key, but adding a new element with the same key?

Also, the combination of `not`, `null` and `filter` is needlessly complicated. You can just use

```
       hasElement = any ((==key).fst) lst
```

Finally, the signature `Num a => ...` is actually not strong enough: you're comparing keys with `==`. That only works if the keys have an `Eq` instance. So, this is the correct signature:

```
(Eq a, Num t) => (a, t) -> [(a, t)] -> [(a, t)]
```

Comment: Thanks for nice explanation. Using pattern matching is much more ele

Comment: Thanks for nice explanation. I got the error I committed and understood how elegant is pattern matching in this case.
And now I noticed that the function itself is wrong since I need to update the list with the tuple it it exists already instead of adding it again. 
Thanks!